# Facing issue on adding ios platform for PhoneGap

Tags: ios, cordova

I am tring to add ios platform project for Phonegap using CLI but failing with following issue.

```
Creating ios project...
xcrun: Error: could not stat active Xcode path '/Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer'. (No such file or directory)
Cordova can only run in Xcode version 4.6 or greater.
Error: /Users/Mahmood1/.cordova/lib/ios/cordova/3.4.1/bin/create: Command failed with exit code 2
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/superspawn.js:126:23)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:5)
```

Note : i have two version of xcode is installed in applications ie. xcode 5.1 and xcode 4.6.Where xcode 5.1 is name as "xcode" and xcode 4.6 named as "xcode2".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**more information** on the xcode-select command if you have installed Xcode in a different location

The **“Error:** No developer directory found at /Developer” message is displayed if the create script can not find the location of the command line tools within Xcode. This can occur if more than one version of Xcode is installed on the system or when upgrading from older versions of Xcode. The solution is to run the xcode-select command to set the location. If you have installed Xcode in the default location the command to execute is:

more Information https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcode-select.1.html

Comment: I set active developer library by using "xcode-select" command and it resolved my issue.Follwing command i fired : " xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app" . Thanks :-)